# Does every odd prime power divide a number of the form $\ n^{n-1}+n-1\ $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, perfect-powers

A conjecture motivated by a factoring project :

> For every odd prime power $\ P\ $ , there is an integer $\ n>1\ $ such that $\ P\mid n^{n-1}+n-1\ $. In other words , every odd prime power divides some number of the form $n^{n-1}+n-1$.

Can we prove this conjecture ?

Every prime power $\ p^k\le 10^7 $ with an odd prime $p$ and an integer $\ k>1\ $ satisfies the conjecture which I found out with a brute force search. For the primes however, I only arrived at about $\ P=500\ 000\ $.

I noticed no nice pattern to find a suitable $\ n\ $quickly, so I need (in the case it is too hard to prove the conjecture) a more efficient method to find a suitable $\ n\ $ so that I can at least extend the search limit significantly.

The conjecture is false for arbitary odd numbers $\ P\ $. A counterexample is $\ 171\ $.

Comment: @Henry: If $n =1$ mod $p$, then $n^{n-1}+n-1$ is still congruent to $1$ mod $p$ though…

Comment: @Henry can you explain me what is prime power, I mean what is $P$, please.

Comment: @lonestudent $P=p^k$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thank you.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Conjecture says for any odd prime $p$ and for all $k≥1$, there exist $n$ such that, $p^k|n^{n-1}+n-1$ ? Do I understand right?

Comment: yes @lonestudent

Comment: Currently, I run a check of the non-prime case (the prime case has been solved , see answer below) upto $10^8$. I arrived at $2\cdot 10^7$ without having found a counterexample.

Comment: @Peter Could you include a list of such $n$ for small prime powers? This might help in discerning a pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $p$ an odd prime this is always true. Take $n$ such that $n\equiv 2\pmod{p-1}$ and $n\equiv\frac{p+1}{2}\pmod p$; this is always possible by the Chinese remainder theorem. Now we have $n-1\equiv 1\pmod{p-1}$, and so $n^{n-1}\equiv n\pmod p$ by Fermat's little theorem. So $n^{n-1}+n-1\equiv 2n-1\equiv p$.

For $P$ a nontrivial prime power this approach (via Euler-Fermat) doesn't work because $P$ and $\phi(P)$ are not coprime.

Comment: Superb answer ! (+1 and accept)

Answer (score 1):

For the case of prime powers, I think we can use induction to find solutions $n$ that are congruent to $2$ mod $p-1$. Let $p$ be an odd prime number, $k \geq 1$, and let $n$ be a positive integer such that $p^k|n^{n-1}+n-1$ (so $n$ and $p$ are coprime) and such that $n=2$ mod $p-1$.

Now, write $m=n+sp^k$ for a positive integer $s$ divisible by $p-1$: then $C=m^{m-1}+m-1$ is congruent mod $p^{k+1}$ to $m^{n-1}+n+sp^k-1$, so $C$ is congruent to $n^{n-1}+(n-1)sp^kn^{n-2}+n+sp^k-1$ mod $p^{k+1}$.

Thus, if we write $n^{n-1}+n-1=tp^k$ for some integer $t$, $p^{k+1}|C$ iff $p^{k+1}|tp^k+(n-1)n^{n-2}sp^k+sp^k$ iff $p|t+(1+(n-1)n^{n-2})s$. If $1+(n-1)n^{n-2}$ is coprime to $p$, then we’re done. But $n-2$ can be chosen divisible by $p-1$ (by the accepted answer) so $1+(n-1)n^{n-2}$ is congruent to $n$ mod $p$ so is coprime to $p$.

Comment: I am slightly confused from the "so $C =...$" part onwards. We want to show that mod $p^{k+1}$ we have $m^{n-1}+n+sp^k-1 = n^{n-1} + (n-1)sp^k + n+sp^k-1$. Cancelling out the common terms gives $m^{n-1} = n^{n-1} + (n-1)sp^k$. Now, I write $m^{n-1}  = (n+ sp^k)^{n-1}$, and using the binomial theorem gives me $n^{n-1} + (n-1)n^{n-2}sp^k$, further terms would be divisible by $p^{2k}$ so by $p^{k+1}$. Now, where did the $n^{n-2}$ go? Or am I making a mistake? Why is $n^{n-2} \equiv 1 \mod p^{k+1}$?

Comment: Great catch, thank you! I’ll try to find a workaround…

Comment: You are welcome! I hope you will be able to find a workaround. I'm extremely surprised that I did not think about Hensel's lemma, which is quite comical of me since it seems to be set up for this kind of a problem. If you are somehow stuck, you can try to see if Hensel's lemma is helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon: I think it’s correct now – the fix was rather simple.